# installation difficulties for BraincraftedBootstrapBundle on Symfony 2.5.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I have Symfony 2.5.2 running inside a site on apache on Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to use the BraincraftedBootstrapBundle to add bootstrap to the site. I have attempted to follow the instructions at http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started.html#customizing, but I am not having success.

I was initially attempting to use the sass compiler (my preference). However, with this configuration:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:
            bin: /usr/local/bin/sass
            apply_to: "\.scss$"
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
        less:
            node: /usr/sbin/node
            node_paths: [/usr/local/bin/node_modules]
            apply_to: "\.less$"

braincrafted_bootstrap:
    less_filter: sass
```

I get the following error when I run app/console assetic:dump:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]  
  Invalid configuration for path "braincrafted_bootstrap.less_filter": Invali    
  d less filter ""sass""
```

I tried changing the less_filter back to less to see if I would have any more success with it, but that gives me this error:

```
[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]         
  An error occurred while running:            
  '/usr/sbin/node' '/tmp/assetic_lessjchaNP'
```

followed by a lengthy list of inputs. I'm guessing that it isn't finding the imports, but they are all in vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the sass filter yet because it has to be released in the 2.1 version. Sorry but I can't help with the second part of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jesus. Are you quite certain? The docs at http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com say that it is supported in 2.0.

Comment: Yep - found this issue in the issue queue: https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle/issues/203. I guess I should open a doc defect for that. I'm going to accept your answer on this one, and probably open a separate question for the less compiler problem.